# matplotlib bar plot looks cutoff

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

i have a list of values representing 8 distributions.

When i run this code:

```
            for pidx in range(len(names)):
              name = names[pidx]
              ber = stm_df.loc[x, name].tolist()
              mx_ber = max([mx_ber] + ber)
              mn_ber = min([mn_ber] + ber)
              ber[0] = 0
              sr = pd.Series(ber,x)
              sr = sr[sr > 0]
              rect = axes[1].plot(sr.index, sr.values)
```

It looks as it should:

[image]

But, when i change from ".plot" to ".bar" they all look cutoff
Code:

```
            for pidx in range(len(names)):
              name = names[pidx]
              ber = stm_df.loc[x, name].tolist()
              mx_ber = max([mx_ber] + ber)
              mn_ber = min([mn_ber] + ber)
              ber[0] = 0
              sr = pd.Series(ber,x)
              sr = sr[sr > 0]
              rect = axes[1].bar(sr.index, sr.values)
```

Results:

[image]

Everything else is the same.
What is going on?

Comment: I suggest providing a minimal, complete, and reproducible example.

Comment: The bars are not cutoff. They have a finite width.  Set the width parameter to something smaller.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to color the area under your distribution curve, I would recommend using plt.fill_between as below.

```
# Color area under curve 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Get x values of the curve (a sine wave in this case)
time = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1);

# Amplitude of the sine wave across time
amplitude = np.sin(time)

# Plot a curve with time and amplitude
plt.plot(time, amplitude, color='black')

# title
plt.title('Sine wave')

# x axis label
plt.xlabel('Time')

# y axis label
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')

# add midline
plt.axhline(y=0, color='k')¨

# fill area between midline across time and amplitude 
plt.fill_between(time, amplitude, color='cyan')

plt.show()
```

[image]

In your example, this would mean simply adding plt.fill_between(sr.index, sr.values, color=f'C{pidx}).

```
        for pidx in range(len(names)):
          name = names[pidx]
          ber = stm_df.loc[x, name].tolist()
          mx_ber = max([mx_ber] + ber)
          mn_ber = min([mn_ber] + ber)
          ber[0] = 0
          sr = pd.Series(ber,x)
          sr = sr[sr > 0]
          rect = axes[1].plot(sr.index, sr.values)
          plt.fill_between(sr.index, sr.values, color=f'C{pidx})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say with the info at hand, but I believe that the height parameter of your bar() may not be properly configured. The height should be configured as the max point of each distribution.